# script to write to the database(mysql) three variables

Tags: php

How can i write to the mysql database this variables below ---
message,serviceid & subscriberNo using php ?

The code would be like something below

```
     $myfile = fopen("message","serviceId","subscriberNo", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
     $message = "This is sample message";
     $serviceId="6013";
     $subscriberNo="254768254545|254956219273|254771514662|25495621145|254771514209";
     fwrite($myfile, $mesaage,$serviceId,$subscriberNo);
     fclose($myfile);
```

HTTP request for bulksms
          //initialise the request variable

```
         $request = "";

    $param['username'] = ""; 
    $param['password'] = ""; 
    $param['message'] = "This is sample message.";
    $param['subscriberNo'] = "254768254545|254956219273|254771514662|25495621145|254771514209"; 
    $param['serviceId'] = "6013";



    //traverse through each member of the param array 

    foreach($param as $key=>$val) 


            { 
    //we have to urlencode the values

        $request.= $key."=".urlencode($val); 
    //append the ampersand (&) sign after each parameter/value pair

            $request.= "&";



                }
         remove the final ampersand (&) sign from the request 

            $request = substr($request, 0, strlen($request)-1); 

                echo $request;
```

Comment: whats the end goal? you want an array and turn it into a query string?

Comment: bulk sms--i want to send 3 variables -message,serviceid and subscriberNo as http request via kannel sms gateway. remember it should write to the db and send the message too.

Comment: ahh so its a query string indeed.

Comment: You are using `fopen` wrong.

Comment: @Ghost ,can it write to the db given your example ?

Comment: @Tiampa try/test my answer

Comment: @Ghost its perfect it encodes and very neat, how can i write that to db ?

Comment: @Tiampa continue the comments below my answer not here on the question

Comment: yea ,so how i can i write to the mysql db those values ?

Comment: @Tiampa my goodness, the answer is already there use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to code it by hand, just use `http_build_query()`:

Example:

```
$param['username'] = ""; 
$param['password'] = ""; 
$param['message'] = "This is sample message.";
$param['subscriberNo'] = "254768254545|254956219273|254771514662|25495621145|254771514209"; 
$param['serviceId'] = "6013";

$query_string = http_build_query($param);
echo $query_string;

// username=&password=&message=This+is+sample+message.&subscriberNo=254768254545%7C254956219273%7C254771514662%7C25495621145%7C254771514209&serviceId=6013

unset($param['username']);
unset($param['password']);
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');
$columns = implode(', ', array_keys($param));
$values = implode("', '", $param);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `messages` ($columns) VALUES ('$values')";
$query = $db->query($sql);
```

Comment: @Tiampa i made some revisions, check my edits on the answer, if this did help you kindly accept this answer, that checkmark on the left side

Answer (score 0):

Just store them in an array like this

```
$param['username'] = ""; 
$param['password'] = ""; 
$param['message'] = "This is sample message.";
$param['subscriberNo'] = "254768254545|254956219273|254771514662|25495621145|254771514209"; 
$param['serviceId'] = "6013";
```

now serialize it using `serialize($param)` 
store it in mysql database

When you want to use it, use `deserialize($param)` after fetching data from mysql

Comment: Jay, what if i want to send it as a http request ?

Comment: use json_encode() to encode it in json and use json_decode to decode the received value
1. json_encode($param)
2. send
3. receive
4. $param = json_decode($received_values)
5. use $param

Comment: @Jay, i havent used Json before could you just give an code example please am a new in php web programming .

Comment: its very simple, and there are tons of examples. Use `google`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
http://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP